# How to initialize the SQLite3 JDBC driver in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, sqlite, jdbc, jruby

How do you access SQLite3 via JDBC without using active record?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example that works with JRuby 1.6.6 (in Ruby 1.8 compat mode) with jdbc-sqlite3 3.7.2.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'jdbc/sqlite3'
require 'java'

org.sqlite.JDBC                 # load the driver so DriverManager detects it 
#Java::OrgSqlite::JDBC          # alternate means of same

connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection 'jdbc:sqlite:test.sqlite3'
begin
  statement = connection.createStatement
  begin
    statement.executeUpdate("create table user (name varchar, pass varchar)")
    statement.executeUpdate("insert into user values ('alice', 1234)")
    statement.executeUpdate("insert into user values ('bob', 5678)")
    statement.executeUpdate("insert into user values ('charlie', 'asdf')")

    rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from user")
    begin
      puts "user\tpass"
      while rs.next
        puts ["#{rs.getString(1)}",
              "#{rs.getString(2)}"].join("\t")
      end
    ensure
      rs.close
    end

  ensure
    statement.close
  end
ensure
  connection.close
end
```

Output:

```
$ rm -f test.sqlite3; ruby sql.rb
user    pass
------------
alice   1234
bob     5678
charlie asdf
```

Comment: This is an exceptionally helpful answer. I thought I would point out, however, that I had to execute ```Jdbc::SQLite3.load_driver``` before the line ```org.sqlite.JDBC``` for this to work -- probably due to a change in Jdbc since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Install the jdbc-sqlite3 gem

Then, in your jruby script:

```
require 'jdbc/sqlite3'
url = "jdbc:sqlite:path.to.your.db"
begin        
    Java::org.sqlite.JDBC #initialize the driver
    connection = JavaLang::DriverManager.getConnection(url) #grab your connection
rescue => error      
    #handle error
end
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to do this: `capitalized package or class not found (`java.org.sqlite.JDBC')"`. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Even if someone could tell me how to find out for myself.

Comment: @duckyfuzz What versions of JRuby, etc are you using? Does jdbc-sqlite3 appear when you run `gem list`? The above works for me with no errors so long as I add `require 'rubygems'` as the very first line. I'm using jruby-1.6.4.

Comment: @RobertHaines Using 1.6.4. I have a class with `import Java` in it. One of the methods in the class uses the code from the answer above. When I try to run it, I now get the error: `Java package `java' does not have a method '+'`. I'm requiring rubygems and the gem is installed properly.

Comment: @duckyfuzz Just as a really simple sanity check, does the above work in isolation? I.E. without any of your other code invoked, required or imported?

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc driver file `sqlite-3.5.8.jar` gets copied into the gem directory. It needs to be copied into the jruby/lib directory. Application also needs restart.

The driver file can be downloaded directly from here

```
http://files.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar

http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/
```