# Sqlite Connect with ruby java bridge

Tags: java, ruby, sqlite, rjb

I am trying to connect to an sqlite database using Rjb and the JDBC driver from https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#markdown-header-usage

I cannot work out how to call the following Java using Rjb:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")
```

Has anyone connected to sqlite using Rjb with success?

The RJB code I have so far is as follows and is throwing the exception 'java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/Users/obrientimothya/Dropbox/development/vle/db/development.sqlite3'

```
Connection                  = Rjb::import 'java.sql.Connection'
DriverManager               = Rjb::import 'java.sql.DriverManager'
SQLException                = Rjb::import 'java.sql.SQLException'
DriverManager.registerDriver(Rjb::import('org.sqlite.JDBC'))
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/obrientimothya/development.sqlite3")
```

Comment: have you received any error?

Comment: The length of the question might not be enough to those who know the subject. Give more of what you done. You will get quick and better answers.

Comment: @ling.s please see update with example code and exception

Comment: where is your jar file

Comment: `java -classpath ".:sqlite-jdbc-v056.jar" ProgramName`

Comment: the `.:` is very important

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548035/jruby-sqlitejdbc-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcsqlite

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375954/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by adding the system property jdbc.drivers when loading the JVM...

```
Rjb::load( classpath, ['-Djdbc.drivers=org.sqlite.JDBC','-Xms128M', '-Xmx256M'] )
```

This tells java.sql.DriverManager to load the sqlite jdbc driver class itself, eliminating the need for a Class.forName() call.